# ignore 0 values from a query in mysql

Tags: mysql

My query is

```
SELECT cod_material, (sum(cantidad_actual > 0))>1 AS cantidad FROM ingreso_material  GROUP BY cod_material ORDER BY cod_material ASC
```

my results are

```
cod_material cantidad
321010001   1
321010002   0
321010004   0
321010006   0
321010007   0
321010008   0
321010010   0
321010011   0
321010012   0
321010013   0
322010001   0
322030001   0
322060001   0
322060002   0
343310004   1
391290001   1
391290002   0
391290010   1
395050004   0
395090003   0
395090004   0
395090005   0
395090010   0
395090011   0
395140001   0
397300013   1
```

I need to ignore cod_material that has 0 value in cantidad
I would like to ignore values with 0 how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by inserting `HAVING cantidad != 0` near the end of your SQL before the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

@staticsan's answer is right! But in my personal opinion, below query is better than your (for readability). your query has comparison operator in SELECT part.

```
SELECT cod_material, sum(cantidad_actual) AS cantidad
FROM ingreso_material
GROUP BY cod_material
HAVING SUM(candtidad_actual) > 0
ORDER BY cod_material ASC;
```

your corrected query as follows. which looks better?

```
SELECT cod_material, (sum(cantidad_actual > 0))>1 AS cantidad
FROM ingreso_material
GROUP BY cod_material
HAVING cantida > 0
ORDER BY cod_material ASC
```

BTW, assuming `cod_material` has only one `cantidad_actual` which value is greater than 0, then your query can't display it. Let's say cantidad_actual is 10.

- (sum(cantidad_actual > 0))>1
- SUM(10 > 0) = 1
- (1) > 1 = false = 0